# Android android.util.EventLog.writeEvent

Tags: java, android, logging, build, android-source

How do I see the system written by android.util.EventLog.writeEvent in android? They don't appear in the LogCat because they are system level logs. But how or what interface can I use to see them?

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following in command prompt

```
logcat -b events -v threadtime -d *:v
```